# Find an element by it's href value, using a variable

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do this:

```
  $('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function() {
    var a_href = $("#dashboard_carousel .item.active").attr('href');
    $('a[href='a_href).click();
  });​
```

And am getting the error, "unexpected syntax; unexpected identifier".

Is there any way to do this (have been searching for a while).

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. And what is "slid"?

Comment: you didn't build your selector correctly: `$('a[href='a_href)` should be `$('a[href="' + a_href + '"]')`

Comment: Thanks... If you had said "duh", I would have deserved it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Build the selector like this :

```
$('a[href="'+a_href+'"]')
```

You could also have used [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) :

```
$('a').filter(function(){ return this.href == a_href })
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is redundant

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function() {
  $("#dashboard_carousel .item.active").click();
});
```

Should do the trick already.

Comment: How do you know the `.item.active` element is the `a` element ? There's nothing indicating that and it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I would assume so, otherwise he should be locating the anchor, rather than whatever element. This doesn't really make sense..

Comment: This begs the question what kind of element is `$("#dashboard_carousel .item.active")` and if it's not an anchor, why does it have a href?

Comment: And also, what element whould have `.attr('href')`. Do you want to be clicking several elements with the same `href`? Probably not

Comment: I guess this is used as a kind of reference storage. I would have used a data-attribute in place but this is a frequent pattern.

Comment: Well, I doubt that it is frequent, but regardless it is not the right way of doing it.

Comment: Right, the .item.active element is a carousel picture from bootstrap. When the carousel picture changes, I want to show a specific tab (also from bootstrap), so I want to click that tab (which is an anchor tag)